# Xserver/Xorg using VMWare/llvmpipe driver instead of intel

Tags: intel-graphics

I'm on an HP Stream 14 laptop with Intel HD 400 Graphics (i915 in dmesg). I've tried to reconfigure xserver, but it didn't help. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with 4.16 kernel and 18.1 Mesa. I can't figure out why the intel drivers aren't loading (not showing in glxinfo). I don't see an xorg config file (I'm assuming it's not being used anymore). Also, xserver-xorg-video-intel is installed.